# Random Meme Command (discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make random meme command that sends meme's from r/reddit, but i have an error

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = {
  name: "meme",
  description: "This command sends you random memes",
  category: "fun",
  example: ["x!meme"],
  callback: async ({ message }) => {
    try {
      const url = await fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/random/.json");
      const random = await url.json();

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Random Meme | ${random[0].data.children.data.title}`)
        .setImage(random[0].data.children.data.url)
        .setColor("#FF00A6");
        .setFooter("Prefix x! | Random Meme Generator")

      await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```

I don't know why but I get this error

On the older version (discord.js v12) it worked normally

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: something[0].data.children[0].data.title

Comment: A useful tool if you're unfamiliar or not the best at reading json is https://jsonpathfinder.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After visiting the link, it seems like `random[0].data.children` is an array. Get the first element from it:

```js
.setTitle(`Random Meme | ${random[0].data.children[0].data.title}`)
```

You will need to do the same with the image:

```js
.setImage(random[0].data.children[0].data.url)
```